# Problem with Arduino code, Code isn't entering to while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, arduino, processing

I have a problem with my code, specifically in the void loop (I posted the whole code at the end):

```
void loop() { 
  //Serial.println(unitState);
  if (i2c){
    display.print(i2cDecoder[buf[0]]);
    display.display();
    Serial.println(i2cDecoder[buf[0]]);
    i2c=false;
  }

  //Mostar en pantalla
  //Serial.println(digitalRead(true)); //This line makes everything work, I don't even now what it does, I wrote it by mistake

  if (digitalRead(SW)==!stateSW){
    delay(botonPulse);
    Serial.println("Enter the first if");
    keyValueState= true;
    Serial.print("keyValueState 1: ");
    Serial.println(keyValueState);
    while (keyValueState)
    {
      Serial.println("Enter while");
      if (digitalRead(SW)==!stateSW)
        {
        keyValueState= false;
        delay(botonPulse);
        Serial.println("Enter the second if");
      }
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setCursor(0, 35);
      display.print("Key Value:");
      display.print(keyValue);
      display.display();
      Serial.print("Key Value: ");
      Serial.println(keyValueState);
  }
  Serial.print("keyValueState 2: ");
  Serial.println(keyValueState);
  Serial.println("out of the first if");
}
}
```

I have an encoder, the idea is that, when I press the button, I should enter the while loop, and it would show me a variable in an OLed Screen, which I can change until I press the button again, which will take me out of the loop.

This works perfect, but just once, when I press the button for a second time, I'm not entering the while loop.

To debug I put some Serial.print to get where the problem should be and I realized the keyValueState variable changes from true to false before entering the loop for no reason. This is what I get in the terminal:

```
Enter the first if
keyValueState 1: 1
Enter while
Key Value: 1
Enter while
Key Value: 1
Enter while
Enter the second if
Key Value: 0
keyValueState 2: 0
out of the first if
Enter the first if
keyValueState 1: 0
keyValueState 2: 0
out of the first if
```

I don't get why it doesn't enter into the while loop the second time.

The whole code is here:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

//OLed variables
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels4
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)

//I2C comunication
float keyValue=0; //Key value we are looking to modify in the feeder
bool i2c;
int i2cRecieve1;
String i2cDecoder[] = {"Neumatic Extruder" ,"Stepper Extruder", "-1" ,"1"};
int buf[200];
#define adress 99

//Encoder variables
#define CLK 2
#define DT 3
#define SW 4
#define botonPulse 250

bool keyValueState = false;
int lastStateCLK;
int stateSW;
int currentStateCLK;


float power(float x, int y)
{ 
  float mult=1.0;
  if (y>0)
  {
    for (int i=0 ; i < y ; i++ )
    {
      mult=mult*x;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i=0 ; i < abs(y) ; i++ )
    {
      mult=mult/x;
      Serial.println(mult);
    }
}
  return mult;
}
void getKeyValue()
{
  if (i2cDecoder[buf[0]]=="Neumatic Extruder")
  {
    keyValue=  power(10,(buf[1]*i2cDecoder[buf[2]].toInt()))+255* buf[3]+buf[4]*i2cDecoder[buf[5]].toInt();
  }
  else
  {
    keyValue = power(10,(buf[1]*i2cDecoder[buf[2]].toInt()))*(255* buf[3]+buf[4]*i2cDecoder[buf[5]].toInt());
    //keyValue = power(10,(buf[1]*i2cDecoder[buf[2]].toInt()));
    Serial.println(keyValue);
  }
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  unsigned int pos=0;
  while (Wire.available () > 0)
  {
   byte c = Wire.read ();
   //Serial.println(c);
   if (pos < sizeof buf)
     buf [pos++] = c;
  } 
  getKeyValue();
  i2c=true;
  return;
}


void flag ()
{
  if (keyValueState)
  {
    currentStateCLK = digitalRead(CLK);
    if (currentStateCLK != lastStateCLK  && currentStateCLK == 1){
      if (digitalRead(DT) != currentStateCLK) {
              keyValue --;
          }  
      else {
              keyValue ++;
          }
      }
    lastStateCLK = currentStateCLK;
  /*if (digitalRead(SW)==!stateSW)
    {
    unitState= false;
    delay(botonPulse);
    }*/
  }
  return;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(250000);
  //I2C initialization
  Wire.begin(adress); 
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event

  //Oled initialization
  /*if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { // Address 0x3D for 128x64
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;);
  }
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 10);
  display.display();
  display.println("Hello, world!");
  display.display();
  delay(100);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.display();*/

  //Encoder configuration
  pinMode(CLK,INPUT);
    pinMode(DT,INPUT);
    pinMode(SW, INPUT_PULLUP);
    lastStateCLK = digitalRead(CLK);
  stateSW = digitalRead(SW);
  Serial.print("stateSW: ");
  Serial.println(stateSW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(CLK),flag,RISING);
}

void loop() { 
  //Serial.println(unitState);
  if (i2c){
    display.print(i2cDecoder[buf[0]]);
    display.display();
    Serial.println(i2cDecoder[buf[0]]);
    i2c=false;
  }

  //Mostar en pantalla
  //Serial.println(digitalRead(true)); //This line makes everythin work, I don't even now what it does, I wroted by mistake

  if (digitalRead(SW)==!stateSW){
    delay(botonPulse);
    Serial.println("Enter the first if");
    keyValueState= true;
    Serial.print("keyValueState 1: ");
    Serial.println(keyValueState);
    while (keyValueState)
    {
      Serial.println("Enter while");
      if (digitalRead(SW)==!stateSW)
        {
        keyValueState= false;
        delay(botonPulse);
        Serial.println("Enter the second if");
      }
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setCursor(0, 35);
      display.print("Key Value:");
      display.print(keyValue);
      display.display();
      Serial.print("Key Value: ");
      Serial.println(keyValueState);
  }
  Serial.print("keyValueState 2: ");
  Serial.println(keyValueState);
  Serial.println("out of the first if");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees the main loop:
`while (1) loop();`

Most probably it is not entering your `if` in next loop again because the compiler did not recognize that the `stateSW` could have been changed by anything because it assumes that the code flow is just that single loop. So it optimizes out the memory read to this address by keeping that variable in a register. If there is anything else that breaks this assumption (like an interrupt) you have to force the compiler to read and write it in any case by adding `volatile` to variables that can change state by external means (like ports or variables set in ISRs).

So add a `volatile` declaration to all variables that are set in interrupt service routines and read by the main loop.

(there may be other issues - I did not examined the whole code in details)

Comment: If you check the print out, you'll see that it's `keyValueState` that misbehaves.

Comment: oh - i missed the begin of the setup. the `stateSW` is not written in the ISR. but there  are still some `volatile` issues

Comment: @vlad_tepesch, I changed the variable in the interrupt to volatile, but the one I use in the interrupt is lastStateCLK.

Comment: @4386427, yes the problem is the behavior of the variable `keyValueState`. Also, when I uncomment the line `//Serial.println(digitalRead(true)); ` I don't even know what that line does, because I wrote it but mistake. 
`

Comment: @josetodominguez `keyValue` has the `volatile` problem. But looking on your code in detail makes me questioning if it even can work in principle. you should rethink the whole thing and start from scratch. I think that there are also some misunderstandings how the "parallelism" works and what exactly which component does what at each time. It is nearly impossible to help you since your hardware is unknown (what encoder and how does it work (why does it have a clock))

Comment: This is the encoder: https://www.amazon.com/Cylewet-Encoder-15%C3%9716-5-Arduino-CYT1062/dp/B06XQTHDRR/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?__mk_es_US=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2NYHX1L9L0HP4&dchild=1&keywords=arduino+encoder&qid=1594918252&sprefix=arduino+enco%2Caps%2C134&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExQUhXMU4zWUcyQ1RMJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUExMDMwNjA1MjI0MjBWMlpSTUI4ViZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMDgzOTU5MVBaRklNODVVRlNBRCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=

The code works, when I un comment the serial-out line that I mention.

Comment: @josetodominguez so a simple rotary encoder. your code looks very complicated. this is a god article (in german) that also contains code: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Drehgeber#Solide_L.C3.B6sung:_Beispielcode_in_C   or this: http://www.lothar-miller.de/s9y/archives/71-Drehgeberauswertung-mit-Beschleunigung.html this also has implemented a speed up. the code has to run once every milli second (set up a timer) the main loop can read and reset enc_pos.